# Centering a div inside another div when using nth-child

Tags: html, css

In the code below, how do I automatically center the second div inside the parent div?  I'm using nth-child here. You'll see in the fiddle what I mean. The first and third are ok for me, but the second is a problem child.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epvvL1zy/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Display</title>

<style>

img.thumbnail {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}

.image:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete {
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

.delete .icon-remove {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

.imageContainer {
    width:665px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.image:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left:0px;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+2) {
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+0) {
    float:right;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="imageContainer">
    <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="/imgur/in/IN00011407520181.JPG"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
    <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="/imgur/in/IN00011407520181.JPG"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
    <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="/imgur/in/IN00011407520181.JPG"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
    <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="/imgur/in/IN00011407520181.JPG"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
    <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="/imgur/in/IN00011407520181.JPG"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
    <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="/imgur/in/IN00011407520181.JPG"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've floated all of those divs. centering doesn't make much sense "jam up against the right side, but don't jam up - go into the middle of the line".

Comment: @MarcB What in the world does that mean?

Comment: In the case where there is 2 images on the 2nd line, how do you want the right-most (2nd) image to be positioned?

Comment: @MarcAudet In the center.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not the best way to answer here, but i dont have the time to write the code now. My hint fr you is to try the `display:flexbox`. here you can define the gap between elements i works only in newish browers and its takes 1 render process more, but it should work for your purpose.

here the MDN link, i hope you will help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

best regards

Comment: I did try that, but problem is sometimes there might be less than 3 images, so the second one floats all the way right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix to your problem. Wrap the 3 images in a `.row` div and give `position:absolute` to the center div. See if this helps.

HTML:

```
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/mHg4A13.jpg"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
        <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/mHg4A13.jpg"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div></div>
        <div class="image"><div class="delete"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/mHg4A13.jpg"><i class="icon-remove white"></i></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .image:nth-child(3n+2) {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;

        /*Update */
        width: 172px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-right: 0px;


    }

   .row{ position:relative; }
```

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/epvvL1zy/9/)

Comment: Hmm... Works fine in Chrome, but has an issue with Firefox

Comment: Th width computed in Firefox was `150px`. See the updated css.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `float:left`from all the images

```
.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /*float: left;*/
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and then define the images like this:

```
.image:nth-child(3n+1) {
    float:left;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+2) {
    float:right;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+0) {
    width:150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**It works BUT:** The order of the markup is changed and it will fill up like this:

```
<div> //container
    <div></div> // goes left
    <div></div> // goes right
    <div></div> // goes in the middle

    <div></div> // goes left
    <div></div> // goes right
    <div></div> // goes in the middle
</div>
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epvvL1zy/8/

Answer (score 0):

To complement the @Paulquappe's answer, you can check this very nice guide to flexbox.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For what I understand, what you want to achieve is having

```
.imageContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Check this fiddle, I forked yours, and have added some flexbox properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvw6w4q8/

Answer (score 0):

If .imageContainer and .images are fixed in size it could be done like this:

```
.image {
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.imageContainer {
    width:665px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    text-align: center;
}


.image:nth-child(3n+2) {
    margin: auto 70px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3665j5vg/

Comment: You may want to change .imageContainer width to an even number (664 or 666 etc) to center content nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a more brute-force (but more bullet proof) approach as follows.

Modify the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="imageWrap">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="delete">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/mHg4A13.jpg">
               <i class="icon-remove white"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add a `.imageWrap` element around each image.

For the CSS:

```
.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imageWrap:nth-child(3n+1) {
    text-align: left;
}
.imageWrap:nth-child(3n+2) {
    text-align: center;
}
.imageWrap:nth-child(3n+0) {
    text-align: right;
}
.imageWrap {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
```

Apply `display: inline-block` to `.image`, which preserves the image border styling.

For `.imageWrap`, apply the `float: left` to this element and set the width to 33.333%.

For the nth-child of `.imageWrap`, use text-align left/center/right as needed, and since
your `.image` is an inline-block, you get the alignment that you want.

This will also work for 1 and 2 images per line.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/by1db6b6/

Answer (score 0):

You can try stringing together the different selectors to create sub groupings: [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/tj1zfrye/)
I used absolute positioning to acomplish your layout goal, but the sub selectors like `.image:nth-child(3n+0):nth-child(2n+0)` could easily be used with other layout options.

```
.image:nth-child(3n+1) {
    left:0;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+2) {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -86px;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+0) {
    right: 0;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+1):nth-child(2n+0) {
    left:0;
    top: 180px;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+2):nth-child(2n+0) {
    left: 50%;
    top: 180px;
    margin-left: -86px;
}

.image:nth-child(3n+0):nth-child(2n+0) {
    right: 0;
    top: 180px;
}
/* changed positioning to absolute */
.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```